# How to add build server details in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am having Jenkins in one server and my build server is different. How to point build server in Jenkins pipeline so that my application will build in build server

Using grade and java.

Do we need to use node('Build 1') inside stage?

Suggest me some sample code please.

Comment: Yes, you're right with the label argument for the [`node`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-node-code-allocate-node) step. Why aren't you just trying that? So much easier to post here? ;-)

Comment: I tried that already. It is not working. Posted here to check syntax issues.

Comment: What is not working? Spaces are not allowed in node labels. Please provide more detail, how you've set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins, your build server called slave machine or Jenkins nodes, which you need

**Firstly** add this "buildserver" into Jenkins nodes in advance, then you will get node name (or label them like `ubuntu-buildserver`), see [one jenkins distributed build blog](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_distributed_builds.htm)

[image]

**Secondly** in scripted pipeline you specify/reference this name in node

```
node("ubuntu-buildserver")
```

If you use declarative pipeline, check [syntax#agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) part.

It is similar for other global configuration like `credentialsId`, you need define those parameters in jenkins and refer to use them in your pipeline script.